# quicky getting out of the catch block

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a try-catch block as defined below and a for-each loop inside it.

```
try
{

 // Doing some JDBC Connections here

  Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();

   while(DeviceRS.next()){
   final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("Connection_vch");
       System.out.println("Value of the IP Address Field:"+ip_address);
   connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));
   }    

    for(final String ip : connections.keySet())
    {

      // Selecting and inserting into database here ...

     }// ENd of for loop

}// ENd of try block
catch(SQLException ex){

ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

So, if something goes wrong with the connection, my program will get stuck in the catch block,printing the stack trace. I want to move onto other connections.

Is there a way  can exit the catch block quickly just after printing the stack trace?

Note: I haven't mentioned full code here as I think my question is not concerned with my code.

Comment: Put try/catch inside while block and move those two statements inside while to new try block.

Comment: You're exiting the catch block quickly, you probably wanted to continue some loop though.

Comment: SQLException is thrown by DriverManager.getConnection() so the try-catch should be inside the while loop as mentioned above by Nambari.

Comment: @cooltechnomax I did what Sireesh mentioned below but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your code like this. To quickly skip it on its failure.

```
 // Doing some JDBC Connections here





       Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();
        try
        {

           while(DeviceRS.next()){
           try{
           final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("Connection_vch");
           connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

             }
           }  
    catch(Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("in catch block");
//System.exit(0); // dont use this -in real time projects
        }finally{
       System.out.println("in finally block");

        } 

            for(final String ip : connections.keySet())
            {

              // Selecting and inserting into database here ...

             }// ENd of for loop

        }// ENd of try block
```

Comment: Using your approach is not letting me move on to next connection. It's getting stuck at printing stacktrace again and again.

Comment: How are you making sure here that after hitting the catch block, I can get out of that block after seeing the exception one time?

Comment: if it a standalone application, try to put the System.exit(0); and change the catch block with Exception instead of SQLException. @user3525926

Comment: Can you update your code with what you are saying?I am not calling any stored procedure so my application is a standalone application

Comment: In this way, my aplication just exits after printing stacktrace for one time which I don't want. I want to print the stack trace once and then move onto other connections. @Sireesh

Comment: Add one more try catch block inside the while loop.That will helps. Dont forget to Remove System.exit(0) @max

Comment: I edited the code, Is that the way you are referring me to follow?@Sireesh

Comment: Yes @max , you are on the right track. How it goes now.

Comment: Awesome. Finally after long time, it worked. Thanks @Sireesh for your constant and prompt support. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's fine looking way. But you can make another try-catch block inside your try-catch

```
 try {
     // your code here

     for(final String ip : connections.keySet()) {
         try { // inner catch
             // your code, that will be continued if sql exception occurs
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

 } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said if you want if something goes wrong with the connection and you want to move onto another connection,just do this :

```
 boolean check = true;

 while(check) {
   try {

   Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();

   while(DeviceRS.next()){

   final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("Connection_vch");
   connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address   +    ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));

  } // Ends inner while    

  check = false;  //As connection is ok,we don't need to loop back.  

   for(final String ip : connections.keySet())
   {

     // Selecting and inserting into database here ...
   }

 }// Ends try block

 catch(SQLException ex){

    ex.printStackTrace();

   } //Ends catch block

  finally{

         // close the connection if needed.
   } // Ends finally block

}// Ends outer while loop
```

Comment: If something goes wrong with connection, (check = false) will not be executed,so the loop will be continued to connect again.

Comment: Since you have closed the `try` block before the `for` loop, I can't access `connections` object in the `for-each` loop and hence getting an error.

Comment: Look closer,I closed `try` block right before the `catch` block and the for loop is `inside the try block`.So,`connections` object should be accessible in for loop.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not moving on to next connection. It keeps on printing `Value of the IP Address Field:11.11.1.111` and then stacktrace again and again.